# Could not resolve type: Issue while I am casting a custom class in c#

Tags: c#, casting

It is very weird problem.

I have ProfileBase class and created a list from it

```
List<ProfileBase> profileLists = ....
```

well after i add items to this list from another list name is QuickSearchProfile which is derived from ProfileBase also.

```
var _list = new List<ProfileBase>();

_list.AddRange((IEnumerable<QuickSearchProfile>)list);
```

but I cant cast like that

```
var item = (profileLists[indexPath.Row] as QuickSearchProfile);
```

or like that

```
var item = (QuickSearchProfile)profileLists[indexPath.Row];
```

in both situation, item returns null. Actually when I put a breakpoint, I can see that profileLists[indexPath.Row]'s type is QuickSearchProfile

Where is my mistake?

Comment: do you have 2 QuickSearchProfile classes maybe. Look at the full class name

Comment: @pm100, thank you for your comment. I have just one. Because it comes from web service. I havent created anything. and as you say i checked the assembly name, it seems OK

Comment: then save item uncasted and get its full typename and output it, then get typeof(QuickSearchProfile) and do the same. THe CLR is sayin they arent the same - I believe it

Comment: when i call the typeof(QuickSearchProfile) it get this   typeof(QuickSearchProfile) Could not load type: QuickSearchProfile

Comment: and interesting, I called like that (profileLists[indexPath.Row] as IWiOSApp.IWService.QuickSearchProfile) AND it works. But I am sure that I have just one class?

Comment: `Because it comes from web service` it seems to me that Visual Studio is creating one of those nasty proxy classes that aren't really your own and breaks the inheritance chain

Comment: @Alejandro, aha i see.. Actually I am using Xamarin.iOS so, for web service, probably it creates a proxy.. mmm its very weird.. but I got the problem. Thank you

Comment: @pm100, thank you also. If you want, you can answer the question and i will accept it as right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save item uncasted and get its full typename and output it, then get typeof(QuickSearchProfile) and do the same. THe CLR is sayin they arent the same - I believe it