# ProfileCommon -- casting in run-time fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, casting

**Summary:** Null is returned after casting the base class to the derived class. However, the base class object seems to be OK before the casting.

**Details:** I am rewriting the older asp.net WebForms application to be able to extend it using MVC approach. As a part of the proces, I am converting the Web Site Project to the Web Application Project. In the case, the `ProfileCommon` class is not generated automatically. So, I have copied the autogenerated class definition from the older project and placed it as `utils\ProfileCommon.cs`. Content of the file is (simplified to a single property that was also renamed from the Czech equivalent):

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Profile;

namespace proj_app.utils
{
    public class ProfileCommon : System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase
    {
        public virtual string Name {
            get { return ((string)(this.GetPropertyValue("Name"))); }
            set { this.SetPropertyValue("Name", value); }
        }

        public static ProfileCommon GetProfile(string username)
        {
            return ((ProfileCommon)(ProfileBase.Create(username)));
        }
    }
}
```

The difference also is that I have removed the `virtual` from the `GetProfile()` method and made it `static`. (The `ProfileBase` does not have the `GetProfile()` method; so, it should be fine, right?)

The code compiles fine. However, I can observe the following in the browser (loosely translated, line numbers do not match with the example):

```
The object of the ProfileCommon type cannot be casted to proj_app.utils.ProfileCommon.
Description: ... unhandled exception during the web request...

Details about the exception: The object of the ProfileCommon type cannot be casted to proj_app.utils.ProfileCommon.

Zdrojová chyba:

Line 36:         public static ProfileCommon GetProfile(string username)
Line 37:         {
Line 38:             return ((ProfileCommon)(ProfileBase.Create(username)));
Line 39:         }
Line 40:     }


Source file: d:\__RizeniProjektu\aplikace\proj_app\utils\ProfileCommon.cs    Line: 38

Stack trace:
[InvalidCastException: Objekt typu ProfileCommon nelze přetypovat na typ proj_app.utils.ProfileCommon.]
   proj_app.utils.ProfileCommon.GetProfile(String username) in d:\__RizeniProjektu\aplikace\proj_app\utils\ProfileCommon.cs:38
   Users_seznam.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\__RizeniProjektu\aplikace\proj_app\Users\seznam.aspx.cs:29
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

When debugging, the `ProfileBase.Create(username)` returns the object, where the correct value for the `Name` property has the expected value (debugger knows how to get the value). However, after the cast, the resulting object reference is `null`. (I have to admit I am not very good in C#; I came from C++.) I tried also to split the command to get the `ProfileBase p = ProfileBase.Create(username);` (the object is not null), and only then to cast it to ProfileCommon `q = p as ProfileCommon;` (the `q` is null).

**Update:** Strange. I have renamed my class to `ProfileComm`, cleaned the project, compiled from scratch. There is no `ProfileCommon` string in the directory (nor in the sources, not in the binary files, the *.suo, the *.dll, the *.pdb, not in any other file). Even the filename was renamed to `ProfileComm.cs` not to have the `ProfileCommon` in the *.csproj. The source of the `GetProfile()` was changed to:

```
public class ProfileComm : System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase
{
    ...
    public static ProfileComm GetProfile(string username)
    {
        object p = ProfileBase.Create(username);
        Type t = p.GetType();
        string s = t.Name;

        return ((ProfileComm)(p));
    }
}
```

Now the details of the exception in the browser read (translated from another language): `System.InvalidCastException: Object of the type ProfileCommon cannot be casted to the type proj_app.utils.ProfileComm.`

When debugging, the debugger shows that the type of the `p` is `ProfileCommon`:

[image: What the debugger shows about the type]

I have no idea from where the type name `ProfileCommon` slipped in. Could it be related do a version of the .NET framework? What should I check? Could the `ProfileCommon` class still be generated dynamically somehow?

Comment: `object of the ProfileCommon type cannot be casted to proj_app.utils.ProfileCommon`, do you have your own object named `ProfileCommon`? are you sure you're casting to the right one?

Comment: @DLeh: I have renamed my class to discover that. Please, see the Updated at the end of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET automatically creates ProfileCommon class that inherits from ProfileBase on application start. If you want to use your own profile implementation you need to specify it explicitly in web.config.
Something like:

```
<profile inherits="proj_app.utils.ProfileCommon">
....
```

This way ProfileBase.Create will return instance of your specified type instead of automatically generated one.

[MSDN for more details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilebase(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @pepr, there is no need to rename your class. Just apply configuration I showed in my answer to your web.config. Otherwise ASP.NET does not know which profile class to create and by default created automatically generated one.

Comment: Thanks Vitalij! I did not pay enough attention advice. Спасибо и всего хорошего!

Answer (score 6):

It appears you have two types of `ProfileCommon` you should check your source to confirm this. You could also be more specific and have `ProfileBase.Create(username)` return `proj_app.utils.ProfileCommon` instead of just `ProfileCommon`.

Also for debugging maybe try and see what the compiler thinks the object really is, see this post: [Could not resolve type: Issue while I am casting a custom class in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899487/could-not-resolve-type-issue-while-i-am-casting-a-custom-class-in-c-sharp?rq=1)

---

It seems you're conflicting with an ASP.NET class, I'd either create a new class entirely or create a super class of the ASP.NET ProfileCommon class.

> ASP.NET uses the ProfileBase class to create the class used for the user profile. When an application that has the user profile enabled is started, ASP.NET creates a new class of type ProfileCommon, which inherits from the ProfileBase class. Strongly typed accessors are added to the ProfileCommon class for each property defined in the profile configuration section. The strongly typed accessors of the ProfileCommon class call the GetPropertyValue and SetPropertyValue methods of the ProfileBase base class to retrieve and set profile property values, respectively. An instance of the ProfileCommon class is set as the value of the Profile property for the ASP.NET application.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilebase(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Good point. To discover that, I have renamed the class. The `ProfileCommon` is not in the sources now, nor in the binaries. Yet, it is returned somehow by the `ProfileBase.Create()`. Please, see the Update part of the question.

Comment: Sounds silly but try a full clean and rebuild you might have a temporary file somewhere. If that doesn't work I'll try and think up some better suggestions. Also you can use debug > modules to see what symbols are loaded at run time

Comment: I tried to clean as much as I could. I am stripping the project now to bare bones to publish the real example.

Comment: @pepr is it possible to rename your ProfileCommon to something else? it appears ProfileCommon is a class created by ASP.NET.

Comment: This is what I did as I mention in the first comment, and what I show in the update part (at the end of the question). I have renamed it to `ProfileComm`. But the debugger insists on `ProfileBase.Create(username);` returns the object of the `ProjectCommon` class. This is what really confuses me.

Comment: When I remove the class definition, it complains "The type or namespace name 'ProfileCommon' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"  It seems to be related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11074318/1346705 but I was unsuccessful using any of the linked approaches. Something is different in my code, and I did not find, yet.

Comment: @pepr it's created and linked at runtime by profile base.

Comment: Thanks for your help. but Vitaliy was right. The ProfileCommon is not generated automatically *always*. It is not generated for a Web Application Project. And it seems to be neccessary to convert the Web Site Application to the project when one wants to combine WebForms with MVC. So, one have to write manually the class. However, it seems that the runtime was still confused by the config file info about the profile.